# What Kind of Options Do I Have in MS Project For Storing Detailed, Formatted Notes and Comments?

Tags: ms-project

I am new to MS project and afik, for each task we can add detailed notes to it. But is there a way I can capture more information.

For example, I need to store the details of the task in one note and further need to capture the progress. I don't need just the completion progress, but email exchanges and comments, etc. How do you do this? Is a custom field the answer? Is it possible to have rich text attached to a custom field?

Comment: One issue I have witnessed in many organizations only the project lead has MS project. Therefore if there is an ability to capture all the email exchanges, it only benefits one person.

Comment: +1 Great question! Welcome to PMSE, the site for expert and enthusiast project managers. I edited the title of your question to make it clearer to our community and search engines what you're looking for. This will help you get the best answers possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but I think with your use cases you hit the limit of MS Project. It's a project management tool, but has very very limited task tracking ability.
For your needs you might want to reevaluate what you need from the tool. Maybe a change management system or an agile project tracker is better suited than MS Project. E.g. Trac, JIRA, Mingle, all of them free or cheap enough to try out.

I for example constantly deal with a few bigger (few months) projects and lot of smaller ones (few days upwards) in a small team. I use an agile tracker to do my task management (whast you described you want to do with MS Project), plus collaboration (task management systems usually have good discussion capabilities, comments, attachments, those things).
When it comes to resourcing and other project management things, like scheduling, I switch to MS Project. But I have one single project file there, with a task for each of my projects representing the entire project. So all I need to do is take the time remaining from each of my projects, and can tell when resources get freed up, how a new project impact my team's delivery and so on.

Comment: thanks.. I will accept the answer shortly, I am evaluating jira , redmine etc.. thanks